# Selecting edge loops in the UV editor makes edges marked as seams turn into sharp edges on the model

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm working on a lowpoly character model I've had for a fairly long while, going back to tweak it every now and then, updating for new techniques, doing cleanup and optimizations, etc.
Lately, I feel like I'm approaching the final stretch with how I want the model to look, and so I'm preparing to finally make textures.

One thing I've noticed today, is that when I am in the UV editor and I select an island, the seams around that island are turning into sharp edges. I can select the edges in the 3D viewport and clear the sharp-edges, but they turn back when selecting or moving them in the UV editor.

[image: "Before", a UV island in the character's face.]
"Before", a UV island in the character's face. I am using an auto-generated color-grid texture as a reference, and the viewport is in solid shading mode with no shadows. There is a handful of sharp edges already existing on the model, those are intentional. I have seams hidden, so that sharp edges are visible.
[image: "After", when I select the UV island.]
"After", when I select the edge loop on the UV island and align the vertices along an axis. All of the seams are now turned into sharp edges, without any input.

[image: A second part of the character's face, "Before"]
A second part of the character's face, "Before". This UV island has already been reshaped. This time in material preview mode, there is a film-grain shader in use but that isn't relevant right now.
[image: "After".]
"After". I have only selected one set of edge loops, and the amount of edges converted aren't consistent.

I went to check some other files and I'm seeing a similar issue with my other models, both old and new. It appears that this mostly happens when alt-clicking to select an edge loop.

I have been using Blender for five years, and have a good handful of models and textures under my belt. I have been using 2.91.0 for months and have not updated my version, assuming there is a newer version available now. I am only seeing this issue today, despite having done a fair handful of UV work in the past month for other models. I tried looking up the issue online, but all I'm getting is basic tutorials on sharp edges and UV mapping.

It's not terribly important, but it's still a little annoying and would end up with more work for me later if I don't deal with it when I see it happening.

=EDIT 1: 17/06/21=

So I have looked at this in some other files and I am seeing the same issue. Even making a brand new file and randomly unwrapping a sphere. I suspected that this only happened on edges marked as seams, so I removed all seams prior to each test. I had even selected a few faces on the UV islands and split them apart in the UV editor, for further testing.

I found that ctrl-clicking, shift-clicking, and using any selection tools does not do this bug. Alt-clicking seems to mostly be the same, as long as it is in the middle of a UV island. I alt-clicked around the outermost edges of a UV island, and the bug happened. This does not happen when selecting faces or the entire UV island.

Suspecting that it may be something in my user preferences, I made a backup of my configs and started a new factory-reset file. Navigating the wildly different controls, I did the same experiment with the sphere, and found the same results.

[image: I have created a new sphere, adding random seams and unwrapping. I then removed seams just to be sure.]
[image: I selected an edge loop via alt-click, and there are sharp edges around the seams.]
[image: I have separated a handful of faces from an island, and then selected an outer edge loop. There are no seams, but there are sharp edges where they would be.]
[image: Interesting. The edge-loop selection bug only happens along the outermost edges of a UV island.]

It appears that this issue of selecting and moving edge loops in UV islands is in the base version of Blender 2.91.0 itself. While it is more of a mild annoyance at most, I may end up updating my version of blender if it gets too much of a hassle.